# Using Deques for sliding window problems

Tags: arrays, algorithm, deque, sliding-window, prefix-sum

I was looking at the problem [Shortest Subarray with Sum at Least K](https://leetcode.com/problems/shortest-subarray-with-sum-at-least-k/) where the most optimal solution uses a deque.

Since the array can have both positive and negative values, using the two pointer technique will not work. I understand why the 2 pointer technique will not work.

My understanding of the optimal solution that uses a deque is as follows:

- In this solution all possible start values for the shortest subarray are held in a deque.
- The deque stores prefix sum values of the array so that we can calculate the sum between the start and the current element in constant time.
- The deque is monotonically increasing because if we have a `prefix = [a, b, c]` and `prefix[b] < prefix[a]` then `(c-b) > (c-a)` and since `[b,c]` is smaller than `[a,b,c]` the deque is monotonically increasing.

The code for shortest subarray with sum at least k is below:

```
public int shortestSubarray(int[] a, int k) {
    Deque<Integer> deque = new LinkedList<>();
    int res = a.length+1;
    
    int[] prefix = new int[a.length+1];
    for(int i = 1; i<prefix.length; i++)
        prefix[i] = prefix[i-1] + a[i-1];
    
    for(int i = 0; i<prefix.length; i++) {
        // increment start pointer when condition is violated 
        // this first while loop is same as what happens in the 2 pointer approach
        while(!deque.isEmpty() && prefix[i] - prefix[deque.peekLast()] >= k) {
            res = Math.min(res, i - deque.peekLast());
            deque.removeLast();
        }
        
        // this is what changes the solution from 2 pointer
        // we filter out candidates that cannot be the start for min subarray
        while(!deque.isEmpty() && prefix[i] <= prefix[deque.peekFirst()]) {
            deque.removeFirst();
        }
        
        deque.addFirst(i);
    }
    
    return res == a.length+1? -1 : res;
}
```

I think I understand why this particular solution works however I am still confused about when deques can be used to optimize sliding window problems.

---

**My Question**

I started to think about what would change if the problem was to find the **Longest Subarray with Sum at Least K** instead of the shortest subarray.

1. If I change the problem such that I need to find the Longest Subarray with Sum at Least K, can I still use a deque in a similar manner?
2. If a deque can be used what will the solution look like? How can you account for all the different starting positions? We could try making it a monotonically decreasing queue but I don't think that solves the problem.
3. If a deque cannot be used to solve the problem in O(n) time then why is that the case?